# Long boot time after upgrade to 16.04; "Lost" encryption on one volume; Mismatch between blkid and fstab

Tags: boot, upgrade, mount, encryption, fstab

I need some help to figure this out. I recently upgraded from Ubuntu Studio 14.04 to Ubuntu Studio 16.04 via apt-get dist-upgrade.

So far so good but my boot time got insanely long (3min+) and I don't get asked for decrypting my sda6 volume anymore. Before the upgrade I was asked twice for a decryption password, once for sda5_crypt and once for sda6_crypt but after the update I only get asked for sda5_crypt...

When escaping the boot screen I can sometimes see how it says "A start job is running for..." and it toggles between two volumes, one with a timeout of 1:30 minutes and one without timeout.

Here's my sudo blkid:

```
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: UUID="1a2cc7f3-1ba7-4197-8927-496921cc9fdc" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda1: UUID="19c14cc5-bd98-4c4b-841c-eb83a29b5249" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0009a15f-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="fd17231c-e5f6-4fbe-86b6-17309ceb55dd" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="0009a15f-05"
/dev/sda6: PARTUUID="0009a15f-06"
```

Here's cat /etc/fstab (sorry, looks really ugly):

```
# <file system>                 <mount point>   <type>  <options>               <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt              /       ext4    errors=remount-ro           0   1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=19c14cc5-bd98-4c4b-841c-eb83a29b5249   /boot       ext4    defaults                0   2
/dev/mapper/sda6_crypt              none        swap    sw                  0   0
#my pi share
#//192.168.0.244/share              /media/pishare  cifs    uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8    0   0
```

I just disabled powerd which slowed down the boot more and seems to be a power control app for tablets and phones - that helped already greatly but I am still wondering about the encryption of my sda6 volume. Something is going on here...

I run this system on a Laptop.

uname -a

```
Linux mobstation 4.4.0-78-lowlatency #99-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 27 16:46:19 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for any help!

/edit
For what it's worth, here is a screenshot of gparted (German; unbekannt = unknown):
[gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVA1F.png)

/2nd edit:
I re-formatted my /etc/fstab and I think I got some more clarity as to what happened. Upon setting up my old OS 14.04 I created two encrypted partitions: sda5_crypt as my root folder and sda6_crypt as my /boot folder. I made it 3GB because I hate to run out of space on /boot and get that annoying error message (I think by default this partition would only be 120MB big).
Now it seems that upon dist-upgrading a new partition sda1 was created which is now mounted at /boot. My sda6_crypt "became" swap partition now.

Is that possible?